# Generating a QR

Tags: php, image, qr-code

Hi i need to generate a QR, (QR  ISO/IEC 18004:2000)

Using some data

```
re= 
rr=
tt=
id=
```

Here is an example of a chain.

```
$data = "?re=AAA010101AAA&rr=CAJR820905IP1&tt=116.00&id= 556bef95-8322-4897-ae65-3b5e9de593f8";
```

I have found this link:

**http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=001**

I have not idea at all, of how to build a QR using my data and that library, can anyone point at my stupidity pls..

thanks

EDIT
Here is the real answer that i get thanks to the advice wich point me in the rigth direction. (thats why i mark it as correct answer). Anyway, someone may need this.

To genereate a QR (CBB in other countries) you can use the library http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Follow this.
Create a file to generate the QR, in my case (/common/qrcode.php)

Inside this file you must insert the code to generate QR, depending on what you need. This example03 its pretty good for this.

include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

```
 $param = $_GET['id']; // remember to sanitize that - it is user input! 

    // we need to be sure ours script does not output anything!!! 
    // otherwise it will break up PNG binary! 

    ob_start("callback"); 

    // here DB request or some processing 
    $codeText = 'DEMO - '.$param; 

    // end of processing here 
    $debugLog = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 

    // outputs image directly into browser, as PNG stream 
    QRcode::png($codeText);
```

Then in your view or page where you want to display the QR, you can do this,

```
$ourParamId = 1234; 

     echo '<img src="/common/qrcode.php?id='.$ourParamId.'" />';
```

Hopes this helps someone.

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: @Mattt: Line 177, are you blind? ;)

Comment: Well, he didn't provide any code... so I took a guess :)

Comment: @Mattt: I know, thanks for the laugh though.

Comment: jajaja XD well at least my 3 downvotes make someone laugh ,, =) i just undesrtand and solve this... Manuals should be for ignorants like me jajaja XD

Comment: There, I gave you one back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out : [example 3](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=003).

A QR Code simply represents a text string.

```
 // here DB request or some processing 
$codeText = 'DEMO - '.$param;  
$codeText = 'YOUR TEXT GOES HERE';
```

Comment: Thanks! i didnt know this... it cost me a lot of down votes jajaja thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, the link that you have mentioned in the question is the answer:

```
<?php 

    include('../lib/full/qrlib.php'); 

    // outputs image directly into browser, as PNG stream 
    QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');
```

So you can have a page which accepts the data and displays the QR code as an image and you can have a script that reads the image and save it to DB or filesystem.

Hope this helps!